# What is the permalink to a blog post on Shopify?

Tags: shopify

Given a product id (PRODUCTID), the permalink to the published product page on Shopify is https://SHOP.myshopify.com/products/ID.

For a blog post, there are two ids, id of the blog post, and id of the blog. How do I get the permalink to the blog post?

I tried https://SHOP.myshopify.com/articles/BLOGPOSTID, but it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by permalink. When you access a product, if you were going to want a longer term solid reference to it, I think the handle serves as a better "permalink" than ID. Handle is used for search engines, and the site map. ID's are more for an administrative view of things, and note that an ID can change if you were to accidentally delete the product and recreate it. Happens all the time I bet. But the handle, that stays.

As for referencing blog articles, yes. They remain a bit tougher than products, since they do have that extra reference ID in the path. The reference of blogs/name_of_the_blog/ID_article_handle is awkward for sure. Why Shopify still keeps the article ID in there is due to some really longstanding old code no one has to see real reason to fix.

It used to be a lot of pseudo-seo-smart people dissed the whole Shopify URL scheme as unworkable for SEO, but I think in the end, they were proven to be a hefty lot of nothing to see here, move along.